# How to change the text shown above filterwebparts in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, filter

I have some filter webparts in my site page. How to change or remove the text shown above the data filter webparts ? I have tried several ways, but its still showing the "FilterName" !! Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the name that appears above the web part, then you can change it under 'Appearance' in web part properties or else change the chrome to 'None' and then you will not have a name appear at all (unless the page is in edit mode).

Comment: I have given the ChromeType="None" already, but still its coming. This will work for normal webparts, but I'm getting the FilterName there in the data filter webparts.

Comment: OK you mean the actual filter name which is displayed above the relevant control?  So what do you want that to say?  You need to tell the user what to enter so it needs to say something and as you say its used in the web part connections dialogs.  No real way round that without writing a custom filter web part, you just need to make it say something sensible.

Comment: You could (though its not nice) use JavaScript and CSS to hide the text I suspect.

Comment: Sometimes, I don't need to show any text there. So, there is no other direct method, other than javascript , rt ?

Comment: Nope - that is your only option AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace filtername with a space.

Comment: But, that filtername is used for webpart connections! How to handle that ?

Comment: I'm using text filter to filter a large list. I replaced filter name with a space and did connection with connections propery and it is working perfect. Are you using this filter web part to filter only one list or with many web parts?

Comment: I'm using this filter webpart to connect only one list webpart. There are 5 filter webparts there. So, in the providernames you specify the blank ?

Comment: If filter name is not very important for you, I guess you can use space, doublespace, triplespace to call filter web parts like " ","  ","   ".

Comment: Ok.But, the webpart connection's ProviderFieldNames is set by using this webparts filtername, rt ? I have multiple data filters in the page. So, is there a problem in using the space as filter name ? All filternames will be blank, rt ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to create connections between list and web parts again. Because when you change filter web part name, filters will not work. You need to create connection again.